# How can I fix this failing Python extension build due to not finding a suitable Fortran compiler in Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, fortran, system-administration

I'm attempting to install a Python extension (hydroclimpy.sourceforge.net) which apparently needs to compile some Fortran into itself before it's installed.  When I run the build command for the extension I end up with an error telling me that no suitable Fortran compiler is found:

```
$ c:/Python27/Python.exe setup.py build
non-existing path in 'scikits\\hydroclimpy': 'hydroclimpyrc.template'
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "scikits.hydroclimpy.stats._lmoments" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build\src.win32-2.7\scikits\hydroclimpy\stats\_lmoments-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building data_files sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_ext
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\g77.exe
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\g77.exe
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\f77.exe
absoft: no Fortran 90 compiler found
absoft: no Fortran 90 compiler found
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\DF.exe
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\DF.exe
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\gfortran.exe
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\gfortran.exe
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
warning: build_ext: f77_compiler=None is not available.

building 'scikits.hydroclimpy.stats._lmoments' extension
error: extension 'scikits.hydroclimpy.stats._lmoments' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

My machine is a Windows XP box with Cygwin.  Setuptools has been installed.  I have installed g95 as well as anything else I found in the install list for Cygwin which looked to be Fortran related.  /usr/local/bin shows g95 and gfortran:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/
total 159
lrwxrwxrwx 1 James None     52 Nov 13 14:07 cc1 -> /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i686-pc-cygwin/4.1.2/f951.
exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 James None     37 Nov 13 14:07 g95 -> /usr/local/bin/i686-pc-cygwin-g95.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 James None     36 Aug 23 11:54 gfortran -> /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 James None 158895 Nov 13 14:07 i686-pc-cygwin-g95.exe
```

Can anyone suggest something else I can try to get the Fortran situation on this machine sorted out in a way that makes the setup script for this extension work as expected?

In case it's helpful the setup script for this extension is here:

```
"""
:mod:`scikits.hydroclimpy`
--------------------------

A collection of tools to manipulate environmental and climatologic time series.

setuptools must be installed first. If you do not have setuptools installed
please download and install it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
"""

version = '0.67.1'

classifiers = ['Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
               'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
               'Intended Audience :: Developers',
               'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
               'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
               'Operating System :: POSIX',
               'Operating System :: Unix',
               'Operating System :: MacOS',
               'Programming Language :: C',
               'Programming Language :: Python',
               'Topic :: Education',
               'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
               'Topic :: Software Development',
              ]

distname = 'scikits.hydroclimpy'

long_description = """
The scikits.hydroclimpy module is a collection of tools for manipulating and 
plotting environmental time series of various frequencies. This package is 
an extension for scikits.timeseries, focusing on tools for the analysis of
hydroclimatologic datasets.
"""

import os
import sys
import setuptools
from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension


def configuration(parent_package='',top_path=None):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration(None, parent_package, top_path,
                           namespace_packages=['scikits'])

    config.set_options(ignore_setup_xxx_py=True,
                       assume_default_configuration=True,
                       delegate_options_to_subpackages=True,
                       quiet=True,
    )

    config.add_subpackage('scikits')
    config.add_subpackage('doc')
    config.add_subpackage('examples')
    config.add_subpackage(distname)
    config.add_data_files('scikits/__init__.py')

    return config

package_data = {'': 'hydroclimpyrc'}

def setup_package():

    setup(
          install_requires=['numpy > 1.2.5',
                            'scipy >= 0.7',
                            'scikits.timeseries >= 0.91'],
          namespace_packages=['scikits'],
          packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
          test_suite = 'nose.collector',
          name = distname,
          version = version,
          description = "Environmental time series manipulation",
          long_description = long_description,
          license = "BSD",
          author = "Pierre GF GERARD-MARCHANT",
          author_email = "pierregmcode_AT_gmail_DOT_com",
          maintainer = "Pierre GF GERARD-MARCHANT",
          maintainer_email = "pierregmcode_AT_gmail_DOT_com",
          url = "http://hydroclimpy.sourceforge.net",
          classifiers = classifiers,
          platforms = ["Windows", "Linux", "Solaris", "Mac OS-X", "Unix"],
          configuration = configuration,
    )

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_package()
```

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran ?

Comment: I have no idea how this works on windows, but I'd guess the fortran compiler needs to be in your path, such that you can run it from the terminal from any directory.

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.hydroclimpy, built with Intel Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion from a different slant: One way to avoid problems with things like cygwin, and trying to get a *nix like environment on an XP box is to take a plunge and go with linux. Lots of ways to do that including dual boot, live linux, or just go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to apply the patch in [this python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue16296), which allowed me to build numpy from source after I hit the exact same error you describe.

Note: I am compiling with VS2010, and you should use it too for all your python extensions.